# Getting error message from Store Proxy

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I would like to get an error message from a store proxy call.

My store looks like this :

```
Ext.define("MyStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    model: 'mymodel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'customrest',
        paramsAsJson: true,
        url: myUrl,
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            record: 'result',
            root: 'results'
        }
    },

    listeners: {
        load: function (store, records, success) {
            if (!success) {

            }else {
                //OK
        }
        }
    }
});
```

It seems to only give me **success is false**, and no other information is at hand. I know there is also an error message coming back because the data coming back looks like this :

> {success: false, message: "blah blah blah“"}

is there somewhere I can get a handle on 'message'?

UPDATE :

My store is called like this :

```
this.psstore = Ext.getStore("MyStore"); 

this.psstore.load({
    params: postBody,
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {

        if (success) {
```

Comment: Provide your code which returns results (Code or API called by Proxy.) You need to handle this in response of that API.

 public String storeLoader(/*params*/){
  if(successful){
   "{success:true}"
  }else{
   "{success:false,message: "Something went wrong"}"
  }
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out your reader's `messageProperty`:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-messageProperty

so in your config you should have:

```
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        record: 'result',
        root: 'results',
        messageProperty: 'message'
    }
```

You should then be able to get the message through the operation.exception property (IIRC) in the load callback. It's also a parameter passed in the onLoad event (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load), so you should also be able to access it there. We're using that on Ext 4 with an XML reader and in our upgrade to 6 so it's safe to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is, but no, you shouldn't use it.

In your case, in ExtJS prior to ExtJS 6, you can easily read the whole raw response from `getStore().getProxy().getReader().rawData`, unless you have set `keepRawData:false` in the reader definition. This comes with a big **but**.

In 6.0, the raw response data is dropped really early if you don't use [`keepRawData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.data.reader.Reader.html#cfg-keepRawData) on the reader. Reason, quote from the docs: **Note that starting with Ext JS 6.0 the default behavior has been changed to not keep the raw data because of the high potential for memory leaks.**

Because of that, I have added an override on my reader for ExtJS 6.0.1:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.override.JsonReader", {
    override:"Ext.data.reader.Json",
    /**
     * Make additional processing available on the raw response.
     */
    processRawResponse:null,
    getResponseData:function(response) {
        if(this.processRawResponse) this.processRawResponse(response);
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

So now I can add on every reader a processRawResponse function as needed, like this one:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    groupParam: false,
    startParam:false,
    limitParam:false,
    pageParam:false,
    sortParam:false,
    url: '../api/AdminPanel/ACLRules',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data',
        processRawResponse:function(response) {
            var responseText = Ext.decode(response.responseText, true);
            if(responseText && responseText.message) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('ERROR',responseText.message);
            }
```

You can try whether this works in ExtJS 4 as well; [from the source code, it seems so](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Json2.html#Ext-data-reader-Json-method-getResponseData). Otherwise, only minor changes should be required.

If your error messages come in the same property every time and need the same handling every time, you could as well process them globally, directly from the override, e.g. if you get an array of debug information:

```
getResponseData:function(response) {
    if(this.processRawResponse) this.processRawResponse(response);
    var debugList = Ext.getCmp("debugList"),
        shorten = function(tex) {
            return tex.substring(0,500).replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,"<br>");
        },
        returned = "";
    try {
        returned = response.responseText;
        var decodedData = Ext.decode(returned);
        if(decodedData.Debug) this.rawDebugData = decodedData.Debug;
        return decodedData;
    } catch (ex) {
        var caption = "Decoding error",
            message = "The server has returned malformed JSON.",
            box = Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox',{});
        try {
            var jsonStart = Math.min(returned.indexOf('['), returned.indexOf('{'));
            if(jsonStart>0) {
                message = (message + "\n" + returned.substring(0,jsonStart));
                returned = returned.substring(jsonStart);
            }
            else {
                message = (message + "\n" + returned);
            }
        } catch (e) {
        }
        if(!debugList) box.alert(caption,shorten(message));
        if(debugList) debugList.setValue(debugList.getValue()+caption+': '+message+'\n');
        return Ext.decode(returned, true) || {};
    }
},
```

Comment: wow thanks. I had no idea it was so complex. I am thinking of just switching to a simple Ajax call instead of using Proxies. Proxies seem to be more of a headache than they are worth.

Comment: basically, what is the advanage of using proxies? Does it have advantages when using small granular CRUD like operations? But for a simple dump of data in a table.. then an AJAX call would suffice, and be more appropriate right?

Comment: IMO, the simple override for the reader is not complicated. My complicated override at the bottom is because I am trying to process responses which contain non-JSON parts. Don't ask what exactly is happening there, I already forgot ;-) Proxies are of use if you need a store with all CRUD operations. The biggest advantage of a simple Ajax call, on the other hand, would be that you can bundle the data to fill multiple stores at once if you want. This would reduce the number of calls to the server.

Comment: You don't need to do all of this. A proxy fires an `exception` event when success is false where you can get the error from the operation. Here is a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1qbj